# sql missing expression on select query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get rid of duplicate job roles before the data is entered into my actual dimensions table, everytime I run my script I keep getting a missing expression error and im not sure why, any help would be mostly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO job_role_dim (
SELECT job_role_id.nextval, DISTINCT job_role_desc
FROM temp_job_role_dim);
```

Comment: Your placement of the `DISTINCT` keyword suggests that you have a different expectation for its effect than the effect it actually has.  `DISTINCT` does not qualify individual columns; rather it qualifies the overall `SELECT` clause, instructing that no duplicate *rows* be returned.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have the parentheses around the query, and your `distinct` is in the wrong place. You're possibly trying to avoid doing this:

```
INSERT INTO job_role_dim
SELECT DISTINCT job_role_id.nextval,job_role_desc
FROM temp_job_role_dim;
```

... which doesn't remove the duplicates, but just gives them different sequence values. So you need a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO job_role_dim
SELECT job_role_id.nextval, job_role_desc
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT job_role_desc
  FROM temp_job_role_dim
);
```

The inline view finds the distinct/unique values; the outer query then gives a sequence value to each of those.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration on Alex's answer.  The better way to write this query is using a list of columns for the select.  This is generally a really good idea -- and for other reasons than just the parentheses around the query.  So:

```
INSERT INTO job_role_dim(job_role_id, job_role_desc) -- making up these column names
    SELECT job_role_id.nextval, job_role_desc
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT job_role_desc
          FROM temp_job_role_dim
         ) t;
```

That is, SQL expects the parentheses after the table to contain a list of columns.  And, that is how you should write your `INSERT` statements.  The parser gets confused when you include a subquery, because it is expecting a list of columns.